# Why aren't cmath's pow and sqrt templates?

Tags: c++, pow, sqrt, cmath

As a matter of curiosity, why are `std::sqrt` and `std::pow` overloaded just for a single type of parameter? Why are they not implemented as function/functor templates?

Comment: By "a single type", do you mean that each overload is for a single type, or do you mean that there is only one declaration for type `double`? There are overloads for `float`, `double`, and `long double` (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They *are* overloaded for types `float`, `double`, and `long double`.

There are no other floating-point types, so there would be no advantage in a more general solution using templates.

The C++ `<cmath>` header is almost, but not quite, a copy of C's `<math.h>` header.

C doesn't have overloading, so it provides three different square root functions:

```
float sqrtf(float arg);
double sqrt(double arg);
long double sqrtl(long double arg);
```

and similarly for the other floating-point functions.

C++'s `<cmath>` provides those functions *and* overloaded versions of `sqrt` for all three floating-point types.

Here's an example that demonstrates this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    auto f = std::sqrt(2.0F);
    auto d = std::sqrt(2.0);
    auto ld = std::sqrt(2.0L);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(64);
    std::cout << ' ' << sizeof f << ' '  << f  << '\n';
    std::cout << ' ' << sizeof d << ' '  << d  << '\n';
    std::cout        << sizeof ld << ' ' << ld << '\n';
}
```

The output on my system, demonstrating different size and precision for each call:

```
 4 1.41421353816986083984375
 8 1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125
16 1.4142135623730950487637880730318329369765706360340118408203125
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'c' in `<cmath>` literally means that it is a collection of C library functions. By analogy, `<stdio.h>` can be included in C++ as `<cstdio>` etc. and since C doesn't have templates, then neither does anything in `<cmath>`.

Aside from that, what would parameterizing the type get you? These functions take and return `double`s, which you can always covert to a plain `int` or a `float` if that's what you need.

I stand corrected on the second point: as M.A. and Francois Andrieux point out, there are situations where this would be useful. However, I believe the answer still stands as far as `<cmath>` is concerned.

Comment: In the case of `std::pow`, integer exponentiation can be implemented more efficiently (+accurately), so cast to and from double not be ideal.

Comment: Okay, but I'd wager that most FPUs do this in hardware nowadays and that you're unlikely to find an equivalent that operates on integers.

Comment: @dandan78 The fact that such a template was actually added to the language is strong evidence that it is reasonable to want a templated version of the function.